# Fill a new columns depending on others hierarchical values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello  I have a df such as :

```
  COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
1   G1    <NA>       A unknown
2   G2       B    <NA>    <NA>
3   G3    <NA>    <NA>       D
4   G4       C unknown       A
5   G5       D       A       B
6   G6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
7   G7 unknown    <NA>    <NA>
8   G8 unknown       B    <NA>
```

and I would like to create a new `COL5` where I put :

- if `COL2 %isin% c('NA','unknown')` I put **`COL3`** value, else I put `**COL2**` value
- if `COL3 %isin% c('NA','unknown')` I put **`COL4`** value, else I put `**COL3**` value
- if `all COL %isin% c('NA')` I put **"NA"** or if `all COL %isin% c('unknown')` I put **'unknown'**

So there is a hierarchical order where I prefer to put `COL2>COL3>COL4` values into `COL5`.

and I should get :

```
  COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4  COL5 
1   G1    <NA>       A unknown  A
2   G2       B    <NA>    <NA>  B
3   G3    <NA>    <NA>       D  D
4   G4       C unknown       A  C
5   G5       D       A       B  D
6   G6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
7   G7 unknown    <NA>    <NA>  unknown
8   G8 unknown    B       <NA>  B
```

Does someone have an idea ?
Here are the data

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(1:8, .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", 
"G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8"), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D", "Unknown"
), class = "factor"), COL3 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L, 
NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "unknown"), class = "factor"), 
    COL4 = structure(c(4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "D", "unknown"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: See `help("case_when")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you can consider, putting your data into long form using `pivot_longer`. If you remove all `NA` and `unknown` from your data, you can set `COL5` to be the `first` value within each `COL1` group. Then, join your results back to your original data. You also would need to substitute the missing values with `COL2` which may be either `NA` or `unknown` (situations when there is no value to include).

Also, you may need to consider capital and small “U” in unknown if that is an issue.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -COL1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value) & value != "Unknown") %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarise(COL5 = first(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(COL5 = replace(COL5, is.na(COL5), COL2)) %>%
  relocate(COL5, .after = COL4) %>%
  arrange(COL1)
```

**Output**

```
  COL1  COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5   
  <fct> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>  
1 G1    NA      A       unknown A      
2 G2    B       NA      NA      B      
3 G3    NA      NA      D       D      
4 G4    C       unknown A       C      
5 G5    D       A       B       D      
6 G6    NA      NA      NA      NA     
7 G7    Unknown NA      NA      Unknown
8 G8    Unknown B       NA      B
```

Comment: Hello thank you very uch for your help but I get an error message : ```x unable to find an inherited method for function 'first' for signature '"factor"'``` do you know what is going on ?

Comment: @chippycentra Was this on the example data above, or other data you have? Can you try `dplyr::first` instead of just `first` above? And maybe restart an R session too? I was able to run this with your example data above, but there are other `first` functions outside of `dplyr` that may cause conflict.

Comment: Ok in fact I neded to install the library library(pastecs)

Comment: `pastecs` has a `first` function - but I was using `first` from `dplyr` - a namespace conflict will give you that kind of error

Comment: when I mentioned `library(tidyverse)` you really just need `dplyr` and `tidyr` - my apologies for any confusion